# Layout XML - Custom Layout Update not being used

Tags: magento-1.9, layout

I have set a layout update for a category in the admin (Custom Layout Update).

[image]
Here is the code incase that is not legible

```
<reference name="product_list">
    <action method="setTemplate"><template>catalog/product/list-sub-categories.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
<reference name="left">
    <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnav" before="-promo.container.1" template="catalog/navigation/left-main.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

This isn't reflected on that category page. The template used is still the default catalog/product/list.phtml

[image]

I have written an observer on "controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_before" to log the layout xml. At the very end of the log file the custom xml is present.

```
<reference name="product_list">
    <action method="setTemplate"><template>catalog/product/list-sub-categories.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
<reference name="left">
    <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnav" before="-promo.container.1" template="catalog/navigation/left-main.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

Caching is switched off and I've flushed the cache a few time to make sure. I'm a bit puzzled on this one. Anyone come across something similar? Or suggest further debugging steps.

Comment: can you tell me what you want with this code ?

Comment: I want to use catalog/product/list-sub-categories.phtml template file for this category.
Even though it's last in the XML, Magento is still loading catalog/product/list.phtml. 
Just wondered if anyone else had had an issue like this and how to approach solving it.

Comment: so use {{block}} in cms block and set this block in category

Comment: what's the complete path of `list-sub-categories.phtml` file ?

Comment: app/design/frontend/pass-rwd/default/template/catalog/product/list-sub-categories.phtml

Comment: If I set 

`<reference name="product_list">
    <action method="setTemplate"><template>catalog/product/list-sub-categories.phtml</template></action>
</reference>`
in under <catalog_category_default> in local.xml then it works fine, but that applies to all categories and I just want certain ones.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems correct, check logs or third party extensions.

There is also one other way to do this by `local.xml` . You can use a handle like `<CATEGORY_[ID]>` :

```
<CATEGORY_4>
    <reference name="product_list">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>catalog/product/list-sub-categories.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</CATEGORY_4>

<CATEGORY_20>
    <reference name="product_list">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>catalog/product/list-sub-categories.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</CATEGORY_20>
```

Here, **4** and **20** are `category_id` for which you want to use `list-sub-categories.phtml` template. You can add as many handles as you want.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll take a look at third party extensions.

I've already got a CATEGORY_110 layout handle in place set for a one off style change. Was hoping to avoid this as there's a lot of categories and all the xml template changes are already in place in the admin. (It's a reskin of an exisiting site we inherited).